# objc_property_t iOS issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If I understood from docs with this :

```
objc_property_t theProperty = class_getProperty([self class], [name UTF8String]);
```

I get the referance to the property. I don't understand how to "cast" this struct to UIImageView *imageView_1 for example, to be able to set image to this imageVIew_1.

Comment: The line is there, I didn't do the typecast but I was expected something like UILabel *label = (UILabel *)theProperty, but it can't go that way :)

Answer (score 1):

`objc_property_t` is an opaque type. It's basically a C struct describing the property, at the class level.
It has nothing to do with a value for a specific instance.

So in other words, you can't get a property value using `class_getProperty`.

Also remember that a property implies a getter method. So if you want to access a property, you can call the getter method.

Note that you can get the value for an instance variable by using the `object_getInstanceVariable` function.

```
Ivar object_getInstanceVariable(id obj, const char *name, void **outValue)
```

**By the way, why are you using the runtime to access a property?**

Maybe you are doing some very complicated reflection stuff, but otherwise, I'll suggest to avoid the runtime.

What's wrong with:

```
object.propName
```

or

```
[ object propName ];
```

?

Comment: part1: I will try to explain it, maybe then it has more sense to you ;)

Lets say app is waiting for some data from ws, when data becomes available you need to present it on view. There is one piece of data which is some value and based on that value you need to show some images.

It is float value i.e. 3.47. Based on that value you need to show 3 images, and because fraction part is  less than 0.5, 4th image should be presented in other way. When you calculate these full parts and fraction you need to figure out which images you need to show...

Comment: part2: There is row of 10 of images on view, and because here is 3 and a half, first 3 should be presented in one way, and 4th in other way.

For me it was logic to get an array of property names which are responsible for those images, and the only problem was how to "cast" that opaque pointer to UIImage. And with that I will get a reference to which property=image needs to be updated.
I tried to avoid "if else" based on property name, thats why ask is it possible to "cast", and I admit that I am not so familiar with C stuff, long time no see, since 2nd year of college.

Comment: part3: In addition if you have some better idea, I am eager to accept it and to implement in that way. I admit that there are many others, maybe better and easier approaches but this was logic to me at the time of writing. (sorry this is my first comment, it is limited to 500 something characters and I didn't know how to put in one or if it is possible :) )

Answer (score 1):

Hm, how to put this but there is much easier way to solve this problem and its name is KVC.
Something like this :

```
UIImageView *img = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", floor(myFloat)]];
```

Obviously because of lack of knowledge I choose a harder way with runtime stuff. I used KVC in conjunction with Core Data and didn't realize all the possibilities. Well learning never ends :)