# EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception on accessing a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I want to create a class that I want to serialize as XML using the property names and property values of the class. For that I created the following function in my base class (from which I will derive all my other classes):

```
- (NSString*) serialize
{
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    NSMutableString* s = [NSMutableString string];

    Class currentClass = [self class];
    while(currentClass != nil) {
        objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
        if(outCount > 0) {
            for(i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
                objc_property_t property = properties[i];
                NSString *name = [NSString stringWithCString: property_getName(property) encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [s appendFormat: @"<%@>%@</%@>", name, (NSString*)property, name];
            }
        }
        free(properties);
    }
    return (NSString*)s;
}

@end
```

I am assuming that all the properties are (nonatomic,strong) NSString* (for now - a more sophisticated code would come later). Now for some reason when I hit the line

```
[s appendFormat: @"<%@>%@</%@>", name, (NSString*)property], name];
```

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. 
What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean [s appendFormat: @"<%@>%@</%@>", name, (NSString*)property, name]; not [s appendFormat: @"<%@>%@</%@>", name, (NSString*)property], name]; Right ?

Comment: @MSK, right! Fixed it in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Just use

```
                NSString *value = [self valueForKey:name];
```

to get the property value...

Answer (score 0):

property is coming back as a c string, not an NSString. Just change your format to print out a c string instead of trying to convert it, something like this:

```
            [s appendFormat: @"<%@>%s</%@>", name, property, name];
```

Comment: HM, this doesn't throw but doesn't do what I need, that is get the value of the property. I think the issue is that this objc_property_t is really an opaque type as it says here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7336129/1959008. I need to figure out how to get the actual value and then cast it to a NSString

Answer (score 0):

When you use %@ with an object, the compiler basically tries to help you by calling that object's description method.  Your objc_property_t variable doesn't support that method.  I think it's actually a struct...You can't just cast that to NSString.  You need to decide WHAT  attribute you want to print from it, and then retrieve that value from it.  Similar to what you did using property_getName for retrieving the "name" attribute.